# How to clean and add options to the Open With list of apps

Tags: files, default-programs

After installing several PPAs (Wine, PoL) and opening several files with other apps (Like changing from Totem to VLC) I discovered that the Open With option had 2 problems:

1. Many items on the list are duplicated (As seen on the image for "A Wine Program")
2. Sometimes the app I want to use to open is not shown there (For example, Virtualbox or VLC)

So how can I edit this list to clean the duplicates and add missing apps from the list.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough to edit the folder under

```
 ~/.local/share/applications
```

You may find numinous listings for wine there and can edit it. You could also remove it and generate another file.

Comment: Well dude, that is awesome. It solved everything. Like always thanks blue.

Comment: yo! glad to help